# fetch data from firebase collections inside a collections dynamically in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am unable to fetch data from Firestone as I included collections inside collections my firebase looks like shown in image

[image]

I am using code as below but I am not getting any output in the console

```
const db = fire.firestore()
db.collection("MapData").get().then( snapshot => {
   const users = [];
   //console.log(snapshot,snapshot.data());
   snapshot.forEach(doc => {
      console.log(doc);
      doc.forEach(x => {
          console.log(x);
      })
   }
})
.catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Answer (score 1):

Firestor queryies are shallow and don't consider documents in subcollections.  Your query will only find documents immediately within the MapData collection.  It will not find any documents in subcollection nested under it.  If you want documents in subcollections, you will have to build a path to the collection using the names of all the collections and documents in the path.

```
db.collection("MapData").document("GHF...").collection("geometry")
```

If you don't know the name of the collection, you can't query it.